# Displaying a UI List of Strings (Adobe Flex/Actionscript)

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, binding

Im making an application for a person search. I get the results in the form of a string (each line representing one person). I want to display these lines of text in a List, how do I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="PersonSearchResults">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import model.PersonSummary;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        public var listOfPeople:Array;  

        public function populate():void{
            trace("Populating");
            listOfPeople = String(data).split("\n");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="results">
    <s:ArrayList source="{listOfPeople}"/>
</s:List>
```

The problem I am having is that the listOfPeople array populates AFTER the list has displayed on screen... how do I resolve this?

Thanks
phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do bindings with an Array. Use ArrayCollection instead.

```
        [Bindable]
        public var listOfPeople:ArrayCollection;  

        public function populate():void{
            listOfPeople = new ArrayCollection(String(data).split("\n"));
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="results" dataProvider="{listOfPeople}" />
```